# Why does google captures a different IP address than my TcpListener?

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip-address, ipv6, httplistener

I have a very simple http server:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 80);
server.Start();
var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
var ip = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
// ip address in here is: 166.72.162.85

// etc. read request and write response....
```

[image]

I am making that request with my phone that is connected to AT&T 3G network. And my server detects the ip address **166.72.162.85**

**Now here is my question.** I am asking this question primary to learn. Why is it that google captures a different IP address? **How can I capture 2600:387:9:3::c7 with my TcpListener?**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're on a dual stacked network - you have both IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity, which a bit like being connected to two separate "Internets" at the same time.

Your server is probably accessible from only one of these "Internets" - the IPv4 Internet. Google is accessible from both. We can easily check that by resolving `www.google.com` to an IP address. Here's the result on my machine:

[image]

Note the first result - `2a00:1450:4001:821::2004`. It's an IPv6 address, and that's the first address your operating system will try to connect to when accessing `www.google.com` because modern operating systems prefer IPv6 over IPv4. So your connection to Google goes over IPv6, which will see you coming from your IPv6 address (`2600:387:9:3::c7`).

When connecting to your IPv4-only sever, the connection is made over IPv4 - from your IPv4 address, which is `166.72.162.85` to the server's IPv4 address.

To reach your server using IPv6, you'd need to make it accessible via IPv6:

- The machine on which you run your server must have a public IPv6 address
- The client has to access the machine either directly by its IPv6 address, or a domain name which has a [AAAA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types), which is a DNS record for IPv6 addresses
- On top of that, you need to make sure that your server **software** binds to the IPv6 address of the machine. Your code binds to `System.Net.IPAddress.Any`, [which is equivalent to 0.0.0.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspxtr), meaning "any IPv4 address". Instead, you'd need to bind to [IPAddress.IPv6Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.ipv6any(v=vs.110).aspx), which is equivalent to `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0` (or `::`), meaning "any IPv6 address".

BTW, you can try getting your IP from the IPv4-only Google at `https://ipv4.google.com/`. It should return the same `166.72.162.85` that you're seeing in your server.

Answer (score 1):

Google is showing an IPv6 address, your code is showing IPv4.

Note you can also see different IP on the receiving end depending on the route the traffic has taken to get there, like if there were a proxy involved you would see the IP of the proxy and not the actual IP of the source.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/765213/Receive-IPV-or-IPV-based-Data-Using-Csharp

Comment: How can I capture an IPv6 with my code? That means my phone has two ips? I know very little about IPv6

Comment: I see the link shows the answer. I cannot give you the points until tomorrow :/ . Thanks for the help!

Comment: Simply changing the code would probably not be enough. OP would have to make sure to bind to the IPv6 address, and make the connection to the server's IPv6 address.